# How can I interpolate data retrieved from an API inside of link in a pug template?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm looking to add ids retrieved from an api to the url of my link as indicated bellow.
I thought I could do an interpolation so I tried `a(href="https://imdb.com/title/" + #{s.ids.imdb})`. Well, that doesn't work. Can anyone help me with a way to get this done?

```
extends layout

block layout-content
  h1 Popular Shows
  table(style='width:40%', border='2')
    each s in shows
      tr
        th Show Title
        th Year
      tr
        td(style='text-align: center')
          **a(href="https://imdb.com/title/") #{s.title}**
        td(style='text-align: center') #{s.year}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm! I just figured it.

Simply `a(href="https://imdb.com/title/" + s.ids.imdb) #{s.title}`

That solved the issue.